# How to reset Tailwind mobile menu from JS when breakpoint is reached

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

The free [stacked application shell](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/application-shells/stacked) from Tailwind UI has a mobile menu the user can show on small screens:

```html
    <!--
      Mobile menu, toggle classes based on menu state.

      Open: "block", closed: "hidden"
    -->
    <div class="hidden md:hidden">
       // mobile menu content
    </div>
```

In React I've implemented this with a `showMobileMenu` state variable:

```html
    <div className={`${showMobileMenu ? 'block' : 'hidden'} md:hidden`}>
        // mobile menu content
    </div>
```

If a user resizes the window (while the menu is visible) it disappears at `medium` and re-appears when resizing back to `small`. In this case I'd prefer to keep the menu hidden when resizing back to `small`.

What is the best approach for achieving this?

My current solution is to just listen for `window` `resize` events and setting `showMobileMenu=false` any time `window.innerWidth >= 768`.

I'm a bit weary having responsive behavior managed by both JS and CSS but maybe this is typical. Just wondering if React Tailwind developers would approach this differently.

Comment: Why not just use `class="block md:hidden"`

Answer (score 1):

After a few days I landed on the following approach for handling breakpoint changes declaratively and imperatively from JS.

Built on the [react-responsive](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive) package I implemented a small library that provides a breakpoint context and hook (to handle the current breakpoint declaratively) and also posts a notification on breakpoint changes (to handle breakpoint changes imperatively).

If you have suggestions for improvement please let me know.

```js
//
// breakpoints.tsx
//
import { default as React, ReactNode } from 'react'
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'

export enum Breakpoint {
  XS = 0,
  SM = 640,
  MD = 768,
  LG = 1024,
  XL = 1280,
  XXL = 1536,
}

const allBreakpoints = Object.values(Breakpoint)
  .filter((v) => typeof v === 'number')
  .sort((a, b) => (a as number) - (b as number)) as Breakpoint[]

function activeBreakpoint(matches: boolean[]): Breakpoint {
  const index = matches.lastIndexOf(true)
  return allBreakpoints[index]
}

export type BreakpointEvent = CustomEvent<{ breakpoint: Breakpoint }>

function postBreakpointChangeEvent(breakpoint: Breakpoint): void {
  window.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('breakpointChange', {
      detail: {
        breakpoint,
      },
    })
  )
}

const breakpointContext = React.createContext<Breakpoint>(Breakpoint.XS)

export function BreakpointProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }): JSX.Element {
  const matches = allBreakpoints.map((bp: number, index: number) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    return useMediaQuery({ query: `(min-width: ${bp}px)` }, undefined, (macthes: boolean) => {
      const breakpoint = activeBreakpoint(matches)
      postBreakpointChangeEvent(breakpoint)
    })
  })
  const breakpoint = activeBreakpoint(matches)
  return <breakpointContext.Provider value={breakpoint}>{children}</breakpointContext.Provider>
}

export function useBreakpoint(): Breakpoint {
  return React.useContext(breakpointContext)
}
```

```js
//
// index.tsx
//
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BreakpointProvider>
        <App />
    </BreakpointProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```js
//
// handle breakpoint changes imperatively
//
  const handleBreakpointChange = (evt: Event) => {
    if ((evt as BreakpointEvent).detail.breakpoint >= Breakpoint.MD) {
      setMenuShowing(false)
    }
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('breakpointChange', handleBreakpointChange)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('breakpointChange', handleBreakpointChange)
  }, [])
```

```js
//
// handle breakpoint changes declaratively. 
// re-renders each time the breakpoint changes
//
  const breakpoint = useBreakpoint()
  if (breakpoint >= Breakpoint.MD) {
     // render for medium and larger screens
  } else {
     // render for less than smaller screeens
  }
```